# Selectable Primefaces DataList

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am try to select one item of the primefaces datalist. I am following primefaces web site as tutarial. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datagrid.jsf (DataList has the same behavior as datagirid)

Here is my codes.

My bean :

```
@Component
@Scope("session")


public class HomeBean {

    @Value("Aranacak kelime giriniz.")
    private String keyword;
    private List<Customer> customers;
    private Customer selectedCustomer;





//Setter getters
}
```

My page :

```
<p:dataList value="#{homeBean.customers}" var="customer"  >
           <f:attribute name="filter" value="true" />                    

                    <p:commandLink>               

                    #{customer.customerName}                     
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{customer}"  
                            target="#{homeBean.selectedCustomer}" >                   

                            </f:setPropertyActionListener>                                        
                       </p:commandLink>         


                </p:dataList>
```

the page shows proper values as list have. however, when i try to select one item. it does not work.

Any idea haw can i select a item in the list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to make selectable dataList. you should surrounded items with `<p:column></p:column>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Your `commandLink` doesn't have any behaviour. You have to add some action/actionListener or client side callback (in example: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datagrid.jsf it was some `oncomplete` attribute) to `commandLink`.

Edit:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{yourBean.someAction}" ajax="false">
```

And method in bean:

```
public String someAction()  {
       ...
   return "outcomeForAnotherPage";
}
```

Comment: No that is not the reason. I want to show selected item's details on another page. however, i followed your suggestion by adding a on complate widget. it showed emtpy data, but it worked.

Comment: my commandButton works well outside the datalist tags. however, it does not work inside dataList.